# Elasticsearch Aggregation on array of single objects

Tags: elasticsearch

My query search result is of following structure

```
[   
     {
        "_index" : "xxxx",
        "_type" : "status",
        "_id" : "01xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "_score" : 6.297049,
        "_source" : {
          "messageDetail" : {
            "errors" : [
              {
                "errorMessage" : ".metaData should have required property 'schemaVersion'"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "xxxx",
        "_type" : "status",
        "_id" : "076XXXXxxx",
        "_score" : 6.297049,
        "_source" : {
          "messageDetail" : {
            "errors" : [
              {
                "errorMessage" : ".metaData should have required property 'scenarioName'"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
...]
```

I would like to aggregate over messageDetail.errors.errorMessage and create a map alike structure that will hold the different error messages and their number of occurrence in a key-value pair.

P.S. - messageDetail.error is an array of single object.

Can someone please provide any query for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a working example with index data (used same as that given in question), index mapping, search query, and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "messageDetail": {
        "properties": {
          "errors": {
            "properties": {
              "errorMessage": {
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Query**

```
{
    "size": 0, 
    "aggs" : {
        "states" : {
            "terms" : { 
                "field" : "messageDetail.errors.errorMessage"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"aggregations": {
    "states": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": ".metaData should have required property 'scenarioName'",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": ".metaData should have required property 'schemaVersion'",
          "doc_count": 1
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Can you please suggest if I don't have control over the mapping?

Comment: @banerjeesouvik thanks for your reply. It would be great if you can share your index mapping (which you are using), only then I can comment if the above results can be achieved using your mapping or not :)

Comment: thanks for your answer. the requirement got changed, so I did not follow up on this anymore. thanks again for your help.

Comment: @banerjeesouvik no problem :) Can you please accept my answer as well (if it helped you resolve your previous requirement)

Comment: Thank u @banerjeesouvik for accepting my answer   Hope you have upvoted my answer as well 